# 2d array calculator in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm having a little trouble making a calculator. I can't seem to be able to enter the item name, only numbers. Also, it only takes the last price and quantity and multiplies them not the entirety. Update: I made the changes to the code about the subtotal and break,but it keeps telling me

> Error CS0029
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[*,*]'
>
> Error CS0019
> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operandstype'string[*,*]' and 'int'

I can't seem to make it work or add a list to the end. Any help would be appreciated.

```
int[] array;
string[,] name = new string[100, 4];
decimal counter;

decimal price;
decimal subtotal;
decimal tax;
decimal total;
decimal quantity;

subtotal = 0;
counter = 0;

array = new int[5];
while (counter <= 10)
{
    Console.Write("Item{0}", counter + 1);
    Console.Write("        Enter item name: ");
    name = Console.ReadLine();
    if (name == 0)
        break;
    Console.Write("        Enter price: ");
    price = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
    
    
    counter = counter + 1;
    
    Console.Write("        Enter quantity: ");
    quantity= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    subtotal += price * quantity;
}
Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
Console.WriteLine("\nNumber of Items:{0}", counter);
Console.WriteLine("Subtotal is {0}", subtotal);
tax = subtotal * 0.065M;
Console.WriteLine("Tax is {0}", tax);
total = tax + subtotal;
Console.WriteLine("Total is {0}", total);
Console.WriteLine("Thanks for shopping! Please come again.");
Console.Read();
```

I also know that I need to have `for ( int counter = 0; counter < array.Length; counter++ )` in the code too, but it won't work. Thank-you for your time and help in advance.

Comment: Your name variable is an int, and you convert the console input to integer, so that's why you can only put numbers in for the name.  You're also setting subtotal = "X" in the loop, so it will always be set to the last calculation.  You should use += for a running subtotal.

Comment: Where is `array` used?

Comment: I tried to use it right before the while loop, but I'm pretty sure I did it wrong.

Comment: What I meant to ask is how is `array` supposed to be used? It is to store the quantities? And how is `name` to be used, given that it has dimensions completely different from `array` _and_ from the counter 10.

Comment: Array is supposed to be used to show all the information as in show the name of the item, the quantity, the price, and the subtotal. name is supposed to be used as the item of the receipt and when you are done can enter 0 to break.

Comment: But array is of type `int[]` an integer array can only hold integers, and not strings or decimals.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this program will help you in learning `C#`. But you have to promise to try to understand how and why it works. Also, use the debugger to step in order to see how each statement affects the values stored in the variables.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int max_count = 10;

        string[] name = new string[max_count];
        int[] quantity = new int[max_count];
        decimal[] price = new decimal[max_count];
        decimal subtotal = 0;
        int count = 0;
        // Enter Values
        for(int i = 0; i<max_count; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Item{0}", i+1);
            Console.Write("\tEnter Item Name: ");
            name[i]=Console.ReadLine();
            if(name[i].Length==0)
            {
                break;
            }
            Console.Write("\tEnter Price: ");
            price[i]=decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("\tEnter Quantity: ");
            quantity[i]=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            subtotal+=quantity[i]*price[i];
            count+=1;
        }
        // Display Summary
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("\nNumber of Items:{0}", count);
        Console.WriteLine("Subtotal is {0}", subtotal);
        decimal  tax=subtotal*0.065M;
        Console.WriteLine("Tax is {0}", tax);
        decimal total=tax+subtotal;
        Console.WriteLine("Total is {0}", total);
        Console.WriteLine("Thanks for shopping! Please come again.");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

What you have here is a structure (the `Program`) of arrays. There are three arrays each storing a different *type* of value (string, int ,decimal). Later you should learn to make a single array of a structure, each containing multiple values.

```
public class Item
{
    public string name;
    public decimal price;
    public int quantity;
}

// Usage
var cart = new List<Item>();
```

Comment: Ok I understand it a little better now. I was thinking of array as something completely different. I was thinking of it as a value type and not as a variable. Thank-you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to convert name to a number:

```
name = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (name == 0)
                break;
```

Try removing "Convert.ToInt" like this:

```
name = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Also, `subtotal += price * quantity;`